# How to sort the model array before supply to template

Tags: ember.js, ember-model

Here is my model, how can i sort it before I send to template?

route.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(){
    return {
            "fruits":[
            {fruit:"mango",color:"yello"},
            {fruit:"banana",color:"muddy yellow"},
            {fruit:"apple",color:"red"}],
          "prices":[9, 10,5 ]
                }
   } 
});
```

[Twiddle Demo](https://ember-twiddle.com/0193f7f0a3e8bf8aec982a1b97befd1f?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C)

Any one please update my twiddle? looking for `ember` approch.

here is my hbs:

```
<h1>Fruit Prices Sorted here</h1> 
<ul>
{{#each sortedSongs as |price|}}
    <li> {{price.fruit}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>

<h1>Fruit Prices Sorted here</h1> 
<ul>
{{#each sortedPrice as |price|}}
    <li> {{price.price}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>

<h1>Fruit Details Sorted by Alphabetically </h1> 
<ul>
{{#each model.fruits as |fruitObject|}}
    <li> {{fruitObject.fruit}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
<br>
<h1>Fruit Color Sorted by Alphabetically </h1> 
<ul>
{{#each model.fruits as |fruitObject|}}
    <li> {{fruitObject.color}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look into [Ember.computed.sort](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/2.15/namespaces/Ember.computed/methods/sort) or

In your twiddle you should create a computed property in the controller, which would sort `model.fruits` and return the result, e.g.:

```
nameSort: ['name'],
sortedByName: Ember.computed.sort('model.fruits', 'nameSort')
```

The second argument has to be a name of a property which holds an array of properties you want to sort by. Or you can provide a function if you need some custom sorting logic.

I've edited your twiddle. Also I think the price attribute was supposed to go inside each fruit object, not in a separate list, so I moved it.

https://ember-twiddle.com/78e0b3e9ff873a8909221efc87e3ef43

Next time do some research though, [Ember.computed.sort](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/2.15/namespaces/Ember.computed/methods/sort) documentation isn't hard to find.

Comment: I am getting `number` values as stirng. how to convert them to number and sort ?

Comment: You can provide a function as a secon argument for .sort, for example `Ember.computed.sort('model.fruits', (a, b) => a.get('price') - b.get('price'))`.
However, you should define your `price` as a DS.attr('number') in your model instead if possible.

Comment: yes, that' fine. but after we sorting we introduce new value as `sortedByName` will this connected to model? or this is a isolated from model? ( when i edit will it update to model)?

Comment: sorting only possible in contoller? can't i implement the same with `component`?

Comment: sortedByName is not "connected" to the model. It returns a new array and does not modify the original one. The object inside are the same, of course, but the `model.fruits` array is not modified. You can do sorting in a component, why not. Same way as in controller.

Comment: Also when I said `DS.attr('number')` in model, I meant Ember Data model, not the route `model()` method. 
https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.15.0/models/

Comment: I agree with you. do yo have any ember way of finding the `max` value from the array of objects? I require to show the `price` value in the `select` component, so the `max` is the defualt

Comment: Sorry but this is turning in to an extended discussion - try asking these questions in the chat. And please do more Google before that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154869/discussion-between-3gwebtrain-and-andrius).